# What wire size is needed?

Tags: subpanel

I need to run 110 volts AC 300' to a subpanel. What size copper wire do I need? Wire will be run in conduit underground.

Comment: How many amps do you need to carry?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. You'll need to give us more details before we could help you. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: What are you trying to power here?

Comment: The answer is "None.  You use aluminum." Except for very small circuits, or certain cases where a transformer+#12 wire prices out as cheapest.  By "small" I mean how much stuff is being powered; this is measured in one of these figures: Amps, Watts, or VA.   If you're not sure on that stuff, then a) tie an email to your account, b) log in to a real computer, and c) [edit] your question to include a good essay-sized 200-500 word discussion of what exactly you intend to power in that location. It is impossible to answer without this data.

Comment: And if it is to a *subpanel*, rather than a single circuit (unless it is "subpanel that only powers one circuit and using a subpanel as a shutoff switch, which is OK but overkill), then 240V would use 50% more wire but get you 100% more power/circuits.